# Inserting rows Into New table and Appending New Rows

Tags: oracle

We have a data warehouse where we keep all of our records for customers. I need to extract the data from three tables using an inner join. Then i want to insert that data into a new table in a different database server. Once that data is all loaded into the new table i would like to append the new table with only new records from that data warehouse when ever the 3 datawarehouse tables ever get a new record. Would i have to use like a max(create_ts) to only get new records?

I currently have an inner join query to insert data from data warehouse into my new table. Not sure if it will work since its a different database server. Can you someone please direct me in the correct path to achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO table 1(col1, col2, col3, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col5
FROM TABLE 2 CC 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 CCA
ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE4 CCC 
ON TABLE2.CD = TABLE4.CD
WHERE cc.received_date >= '1-JAN-2018
AND table3.remarks = 'Pay Agent'
```

Comment: you need to use a db link

Comment: Correct way is to create DATABASE LINKs and perform only one query over all the databases. Temporary tables are not useful in this case. One query will enhance the "integrity" of result as the result will be from the very same moment from all queried databases. (And yes, the link can handle even different types of databases, like Oracle +MSSQL)